# Flexslider with CPT is not working (Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, custom-post-type

I have added Flexslider, site http://test06.menchasha.ru/.
Code in Header:

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> (function($) {
        jQuery(window).load(function() {
         jQuery('#featured-image-slider .flexslider').flexslider({
               animation: 'slide',
                slideshowSpeed: 9000,
                animationSpeed: 900,
                pauseOnAction: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                controlNav: false,
                directionNav: true, 
                controlsContainer: "#featured-image-slider",
        });
   })
})(jQuery)</script>
```

Code in Front-Page:

```html
<section id="featured-image-slider">
      <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
        <?php query_posts(array('post_type' => 'Sliders','orderby' => 'rand')); if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>
            <li class="slide">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
           </li>
           <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
           </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

Scripts and styles are correctly included.
But slider is not displaying my Custom Post Types.
Could you please help?

Thank you!

Comment: is post_type not case sensative?

Comment: That is how I created post_type:                                                       function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'acme_product',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Sliders' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Slider' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
       'supports' => array('thumbnail', 'title', 'excerpt') 
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

Comment: then post type should be 'post_type' => 'acme_product', right?

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: no problem - I'll post it as an answer, would appreciate it if you would accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For details, read the comments in the question :

The error comes from using the post_types name in the query.

it should be the registered post type identifier.

meaning

```
'post_type' => 'Sliders'
```

Should be

```
'post_type' => 'acme_product'
```